# Dynamically append Javascript variable to URL

Tags: javascript, php

Im attempting to produce a dynamic url containing multiple javascript variables but i only want to include them if they contain information.

These variables are essentially filters which will be used to Select from a MYSQL databse so they take form of "column=value".

The url i am trying to produce will need to be in the format of 
`page.php?column1=value1&column2=value2....` etc.

i am struggling to work out how to include only the variables that contain info and then how to insert the required "&" between each variable.

The current code is below and currently contains just the two variabls but the aim is to have as many as 5.

```
var jsedibility = "";
function chosenEdibility(choice){
jsedibility = choice;
}

var jsfrequency = "";
function chosenFrequency(choice2){
jsfrequency = choice2;
}

function setFilters(){
window.location='search.php?' + jsedibility+"&"+jsfrequency;
}
```

i am then using `"onClick=setFilters()"` assigned to a button to load the relevant page.

How can i set this up so that the URL is produced dynamically, only containing the variables that have data in them and also to add the required "&" between each variable.

Massively appreciate any help :)

Comment: You can filter values first and than join with `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make an array of the variables then use join().

```
var filters = [];
```

Use an if statement to check that they are not empty strings.

```
if (jsedibility != ""){ filters.push(jsedibility) }
var filtersString = filters.join('&');
```

Then in your setFilters(),

```
window.location.assign('./' + filtersString)
```

Comment: Hi @M Y, this looks like the sort of thing im trying to aim for. Im a little confused with the last step though. Im not familiar with javascrip syntax to be honest. why is the `setFilters()` function not `window.loaction='search.php?' + filtersString` ? or am i not understanding something?

i seem to be getting an empty string with the following code too:

 `var filters = [];
    if (jsedibility != ""){ filters.push(jsedibility) }
    filtersString = filters.join('&');

    function setFilters(){
    window.location='search.php?' + filtersString;
    }`

Comment: Honestly, I'm not too familiar with window.location. I just checked it out on [w3schools - window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp). If you scroll all the way down, there's a demo there for how window.location.assign is used to load a new document.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to declare the filtersString variable.

Comment: got it!

I was where i was running the ifs, ive moved them within the setFilters() function and its now working as expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: final working code is:

`var filters = [];
    var filtersString = "";
    
    var jsedibility = "";
    function chosenEdibility(choice){
    jsedibility = choice;
    
    }

    var jsfrequency = "";
    function chosenFrequency(choice2){
    jsfrequency = choice2;
    }
        
    

    function setFilters(){
    if (jsedibility != ""){ filters.push(jsedibility) }
    if (jsfrequency != ""){ filters.push(jsfrequency) }
     
    filtersString = filters.join('&');
    window.location='search.php?' + filtersString;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This works with any number of variables.

```js
// mockup data object
const obj = {
  jsedibility: '',
  jsfrequency: '',
  jsvar1: '',
  jsvar2: '',
  jsvar3: ''
}

// setting object values
function setObjVal(obj) {
  obj.jsedibility = 'choice1'
  obj.jsfrequency = 'choice2'
}

// creating the filter string
function setFilters(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).filter(val => val !== '').join('&')
}

document.getElementById('setFilters').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  setObjVal(obj)
  console.log(setFilters(obj))
})
```

```html
<button id="setFilters">Filters</button>
```

Or another with an array:

```js
// mockup data
const choice = 'ch1'
const choice2 = 'ch2'


const array = []

var jsedibility = "";

function chosenEdibility(choice) {
  jsedibility = choice;

}

var jsfrequency = "";

function chosenFrequency(choice2) {
  jsfrequency = choice2;
}

// showing that it can be filtered out
var noValue = "";

function chosenNoValue(choice3) {
  noValue = choice3;
}

chosenEdibility(choice)
chosenNoValue('') // empty value
chosenFrequency(choice2)

document.getElementById('setFilters').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  array.push(jsedibility)
  array.push(noValue)
  array.push(jsfrequency)
  // string filtered for not empty values
  const filterString = array.filter(el => el !== '').join('&')
  console.log(filterString)
})
```

```html
<button id="setFilters">Filters</button>
```